# Accessing Session Variable in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my ASP.net Web Forms Application, I was trying to reset the Session timeout on every ajax request. I understand that it can be done by implementing the EndRequest Method in Global.asax as below:

```
  Sub Application_EndRequest(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  End Sub
```

But the problem is that Session Variable is not in scope here. I want to execute the following code:

```
 If (Session("_UserID")) Is Nothing Then
    Session.Timeout = 60 * 24 '24 hours
End If
```

Any advise in this regard is higlhly appreciated.

Comment: This means that you keep everything in memory (assuming the default "inproc") for everyone for 24 hours. Can't you set this in configuration? (or explain why not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in Global.asax. this event fires for each request.

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Session 
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Session.Timeout = 60 * 24;
}
```

Comment: I have a control on Masterpage (RadNotification1). Is there any way, I can access it in Application_AcquireRequestState event. I want to change its property like 
 RadNotification1.ShowInterval = (Session.Timeout - 1) * 60 * 1000

Comment: Why can't you that on page load/any method on page ?? You have the value on session now and that is accessible on page load

Comment: In that case, I have to do it in all the pages of my application. I want to do it at a single place.

Comment: you are saying you have that control on the master page. do it on master page. it will be there in all pages.

Comment: But I need to capture all the ajax requests. (Now I am sure that I am missing something very basic :) )

Is there any event in the scope of the master page which fires every time when an ajax request in the content pages takes place?

Comment: No , i don't think so. Ajax request is to invoke a perticular Method.

Comment: why dont you call a web method on ajax request completion. read jquery ajax life cycle. there are variuos event that occure in the lifecycle of jquery ajax method. you can choose one to fire a method which in turn changes the session timeout and then change the content of your contro in html through jquery..

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid. According to your advice, I need to implement the OnAjaxRequest for each page (which are around 250 pages) and access the master page control (RadNotification1) to set its property

Comment: will try to find a solution. i will post if i find one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look at this. i believe this could solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {         



        $("#asp").on("click", function () {
            var obj = {};                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default7.aspx/getname1",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                global :true,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("faillure");
                }
            });
            return false;

        });


        $("#asp1").on("click", function () {
            var obj = {};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default7.aspx/getname2",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                global: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("faillure");
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    });


    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        var obj = {};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default7.aspx/getname1",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            global :false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("faillure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });




<button id="asp" >Click Me</button>
<button id="asp1" >Click Me</button>
```

Do whatever you want in getname1 function. it will be called each time you make an ajax call to the page.But in your case problem remains that you need to call a method of the Master Page. Unfortunately i think it is not possible to call web methods of Master Page through ajax call as Master Pages are converted to user controls at runtime. so what can be done it to create a Web Service(.asmx) file and add a WebMethod inside it and call it with .ajax call as suggested above in the ajaxComplete Method.
Web Service Method would look like this.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
 public string setSession()
 {
    HttpContext.Current.Session.TimeOut=60.24;
    return "1";
 }
```